# Different type while calling an instance

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
#

 def macierz(self, R, alfa, beta):
 #   '''Definiuje macierz przeksztalcenia.'''
 #   alfa=float(self.rad(alfa))
 #   beta=float(self.rad(beta))
 #   R=float(R)
 #   B=self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

  def konwersja(self):
    '''Ta funkcja przeprowadza konwersje listy wsp wewnetrznych na wspolrzedne kartezjanskie.'''
    listaB=[]
    R=2
    alfa=1
    beta=1
    B=self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    lista_xyz=[]
    #matrix=self.macierz
    j=0
    q=self.array((0., 0., 0., 1.)).reshape(4,1)
    while j<len(self.lista):
    #  B=matrix(self.lista[j+1], self.lista[j+3], self.lista[j+5])
      q=self.dot(B, q)
      print self.lista[j], q[0,0], q[1,0], q[2,0]
      break
```

, which works fine, but when I change it to:

```
 def macierz(self, R, alfa, beta):

    '''Definiuje macierz przeksztalcenia.'''
    alfa=float(self.rad(alfa))
    beta=float(self.rad(beta))
    R=float(R)
    B=self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

  def konwersja(self):
    '''Ta funkcja przeprowadza konwersje listy wsp wewnetrznych na wspolrzedne kartezjanskie.'''
    listaB=[]
    R=2
    alfa=1
    beta=1
    lista_xyz=[]
    matrix=self.macierz
    j=0
    q=self.array((0., 0., 0., 1.)).reshape(4,1)
    while j<len(self.lista):
      B=matrix(self.lista[j+1], self.lista[j+3], self.lista[j+5])
      q=self.dot(B, q)
      print self.lista[j], q[0,0], q[1,0], q[2,0]
      break
```

I get:

```
File "./zmat_xyz.py", line 37, in konwersja
    q=self.dot(B, q)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Why, when I call the `macierz` function type is not recognised?

Okay, I think that what I wrote above is quite confusing. Here is a full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Internal:
  from numpy import sin, cos, radians, array, pi, dot, zeros, reshape
  rad=radians
  lista=[]
  i=0
  def dane(self, plik_zmat):
    '''Ta funkcja przygotowuje plik zmat, typu MOPAC do odczytu przez funkcje konwersja.'''
    plik=open(plik_zmat, 'r+')
    for linijka in plik:
      for slowo in linijka.split():
        try:
          slowo=float(slowo)
        except ValueError:
          pass
        self.lista.append(slowo)
    while self.i<6:
      self.lista.pop(0)
      self.i+=1

 # def macierz(self, R, alfa, beta):
 #   '''Definiuje macierz przeksztalcenia.'''
 #   alfa=float(self.rad(alfa))
 #   beta=float(self.rad(beta))
 #   R=float(R)
 #   B=self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

  def konwersja(self):
    '''Ta funkcja przeprowadza konwersje listy wsp wewnetrznych na wspolrzedne kartezjanskie.'''
    listaB=[]
    R=2
    alfa=1
    beta=1
    B=self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    lista_xyz=[]
    #matrix=self.macierz 
    j=0
    q=self.array((0., 0., 0., 1.)).reshape(4,1)
    while j<len(self.lista):
    #  B=matrix(self.lista[j+1], self.lista[j+3], self.lista[j+5])
      q=self.dot(B, q)
      print self.lista[j], q[0,0], q[1,0], q[2,0]
      break

Internal().dane('formaldehyd.zmat')
print Internal().lista
Internal().konwersja()
```

Comment: Is macierz supposed to return something?

Comment: No, it just defines the B array.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your code example if those two functions are defined in the same scope, or if the `konwersja` function is nested inside the `macierz` function.

Comment: The `konwersja` function is indented by one space in comparison to the `macierz` function. Is that a copy & paste mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `return` statements in your `macierz` function. This causes Python to return an implicit `None`. Which you notice in the error.

Change the following line:

`B=self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])`

to:

`return self.array([[-self.cos(alfa), -self.sin(alfa), 0, -R*self.cos(alfa)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.cos(beta), -self.sin(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [self.sin(alfa)*self.sin(beta), -self.cos(alfa)*self.sin(beta), self.cos(beta), R*self.sin(alfa)*self.cos(beta)], [0, 0, 0, 1]])`

This will return the array created and be assigned to your `B` name in `konwersja`.